# Javascript blackjack deck creation

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a deck and create special rules for face cards but this while loop seems to be doing nothing even though I feel I have everything correct. Please help.

```
//creates the deck
deck = [];
Ace = 1;
Jack = 10;
Queen = 10;
King = 10;
for(i = 1; i <= 52; i++) {
    deck[i] = i;
}
while (i < deck.length) {
    if(deck[i] == 1 || deck[i] == 14 || deck[i] == 27 || deck[i] == 40) {
        deck[i] = Ace;
    }
    i++;
}
alert(deck);
```

Comment: You forgot to declare _all_ your variables, danger!

Comment: Initialising three different variables for the same value looks strange. You know that they're indistinguishable (ie `Queen === King`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After your `for` loop, `i` is going to be `deck.length`, so your `while` loop is never entered. It should be another `for` loop.

Also, declare your variables with `var`, please. Implicit globals are bad!

Also also, you can check the remainder when divided by 13 to get aces. And you can do both steps in the same loop.

```
var deck = [];
var Ace = 1;
var Jack = 10;
var Queen = 10;
var King = 10;

for(var i = 1; i <= 52; i++) {
    if(i % 13 === 1) {
        deck[i] = Ace;
    } else {
        deck[i] = i;
    }
}

alert(deck);
```

Comment: What's the problem with implicit globals?

Comment: @user2449973: They make mistakes harder to spot (is this a typo or am I just implicitly declaring this variable?); they don't work in strict mode; if you ever want to wrap your code in a function, it won't work properly; it's slower than declaring variables.

Comment: Ah, well thank you.
One last thing, I was never very good with modulo. Wouldn't 13/13 = 1 with a remainder of 0?

Comment: @user2449973: Yes, the remainder is 0. But you were checking for 1, 14, 27, and 40, which all have a remainder of 1 when divided by 13.

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop isn't executing. i will have the value of 53 after the for loop, so you'll immediately go to the alert.

Also, javascript arrays start from 0. You should combine the loops as well. There's no reason to loop through again skipping items when you could do it in the first loop.